# Load Jquery popup box when click on link tag and show the information from the ID?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have listed some things from a database in a datalist with a link tag. Look like this on front page.

ID= 21 something     click me

```
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <p class="overskrift_bestil">Ekstra varer</p>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>

                      <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_deli" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15"></asp:TextBox></td>
                      <td><p><%#Eval("deli_navn") %></p></td>
                     <td>
                       <a href="#contactFormContainer" id="showdialog2">Show the Dialog</a>


                     </td>

               </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

When I click the click me link I want the popup box to show all the information on the product on ID=21. I know that I have to load some querystring when I click the html link, but I am stuck. This is what I have now:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
          $('#contactFormContainer').hide();

          $('#showdialog2').click(function () {
              $("#contactFormContainer").load("bekraeft.aspx?deli_id=deli_id");
              $("#contactFormContainer").fadeToggle('slow');
          });
      });

    </script>
```

Hope someone could help me

/Tina

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an ajax call.

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#contactFormContainer').hide();
      $('#showdialog2').click(function () {
          var deli_id = $('#deli_id').text(); //get deli_id from some container
          $.ajax({
              url: "bekraeft.aspx?deli_id=" + deli_id, //send id to aspx page
              cache: false
          })
          .done(function(html) { //retrive html from aspx page once ajax call is completed
               $("#contactFormContainer").html(html); //load html into container
               $("#contactFormContainer").fadeIn('slow'); //fade container in 
          });

      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It comes with a syntax erro on this line: .done(function(html) { //retrive html from aspx page once ajax call is completed

Comment: hmm, realized I had a semi colon in there after the ajax call. this code is good now

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a litle bit your code:

- Change showDialog2 id for a class (so you are going to attach click listener to all element with that class)
- Add a data attribute to the link, storing the deli_id

aspx:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <p class="overskrift_bestil">Ekstra varer</p>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_deli" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><p><%#Eval("deli_navn") %></p></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="showdialog2" data-id='<%#Eval("deli_navn") %>'>Show the Dialog</a>
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var clickedLink = $(this);
    $('#contactFormContainer').hide();
    $('.showdialog2').click(function () {
        $("#contactFormContainer").load("bekraeft.aspx?deli_id=" + clickedLink.attr("data-id"));
        $("#contactFormContainer").fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: It is still blank when I open up the popup box

Comment: It is still blank when I open up the popup box